# Flash message not displaying in flask

Tags: python, twitter-bootstrap, flask

I am following [this](https://youtu.be/UIJKdCIEXUQ?t=1451) flask tutorial on youtube, the user doesn't get re-directed to the homepage after signing up and there's no flash message being displayed. My python version is 3.6.4

```
@app.route("/register", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def register():
    form = RegistrationForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        flash(f'Account created for {form.username.data}!', 'success')
        return redirect(url_for('home'))
    return render_template('register.html', title='Register', form=form)
```

In my layout.html, this is a bootstrap template.

```
<main role="main" class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">
      {% with messages = get_flashed_messages(with_categories=true) %}
        {% if messages %}
          {% for category, message in messages %}
            <div class="alert alert-{{ category }}">
              {{ message }}
            </div>
          {% endfor %}
        {% endif %}
      {% endwith %}
      {% block content %}{% endblock %}
    </div>
```

In terminal after submitting the form
[image]

Comment: You don't get the redirect because you don't send POST request, but GET, so `form.validate_on_submit()` doesn't evaluate to True. At least that's what I've gathered.

Comment: Just make sure that your form tag has an attribute `method` set to `"POST"`.